# Prevent non-users from changing urls / ids

Tags: python, django

*TLDR:  How do i prevent candidates from doing and saving other tests by changing the urls while they are doing the assessment?*

this is my first django project:
an assessment webapp that allows candidates to sign up (create candidate) and do an e-assessment, consisting of several tests. They are not logged in users.

Clients can login and review the results of those applications that belong to their client.

relevant models:

- Candidate (the candidate info)
- Application (the application(s) done by the candidate)
- Assessment (the test sequence of the e-assessment)
- Test (the test that the candidate has to do) Client (the assessment
  belongs to a client, so does a logged in user)

How do i prevent candidates from seeing/doing/saving other tests, by changing the urls while they are doing the assessment?

## urls

```
# ex: /assessment/1/register/
url(r'^(?P<assessment>[0-9]+)/register/$', views.RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
#url(r'^register/$', views.RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
# ex: /assessment/1/test/1/
url(r'^(?P<assessment>[0-9]+)/test/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.TestView.as_view(), name='test'),
# ex: /assessment/1/test/1/save
url(r'^(?P<assessment>[0-9]+)/test/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/save/$', views.testscore_save, name='test_save')
```

## VIEWS

and i provide the "next" url after each step of the assessment with the following function

```
def get_next_test_url(request):
    appl = Application.objects.get(id=request.session['appl_id'])
    deploymentList = appl.assessment.deployment_set.order_by('order')
    testList = [item.test for item in deploymentList]
    scoresList = [item.testid for item in appl.testscore_set.all()]
    for test in testList:
        if int(test.id) in scoresList:
            continue
        else: #next test
            request.session['currentTestId'] = test.id
            return reverse('assessment:test', kwargs={'assessment':appl.assessment.id, 'pk':test.id} )

    #no tests left, finished. only set astatus to complete if it was incomplete, to prevent changes after reject/accept.
    if appl.astatus == Application.ASTATUS[0][0]: #INCOMPLETE
        appl.astatus = Application.ASTATUS[1][0] #COMPLETED
    appl.save()
    return reverse('home')
```

Im thinking by some kind of parameter code http://.../?c=XXXXXX that is based on the url itself and updates for every page, but i have no clue which direction i should look for... writing custom middleware?

Or would it be better to use the appl_id that is stored in the session, and check for each object if it belongs to the application?

Comment: Looks like you have a desing flaw - there should be some kind of `CandidateAnswer` model that would reference Test and Candidate and store the answer of *that particular applicant* for *that particular test*. So that they can't modify other answers; only add theirs. And next step would be to restrict applicant to seeing only tests he is assigned to pass.

Of course you can achieve what you want with some kind of checksum parameter, but that's way to much cryptography for what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks for your comment. yes, there are some more models that have testscores etc. but i didnt mention those to keep focus on the question. Your suggestion to restrict applicants to only see tests he is assigned, is helpful after creation/registration. However, then still the issue remains that candidates sign up for a particular assessment with the assessment id in the url. by changing the url, they can sign up for other assessments...! before registration, they cannot be classified yet...

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with your requirements of course, but in my proposal the idea was that candidates got assigned to assignments by someone else, not by themselves.